# How do I view the source of VM(scriptId) files in the Chrome Development Tool source?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

When I break point and every time I open this file, the basic framework inside is the same, what's changing is the parameters inside, I need the parameters inside the file, how do I find out where the code passed in and when the code passed in?such:[image]

I need the key:"code",but I find that the parameters change every time when I turn them on.
How can i track the position of this file???
I'm so confused.
Thanks.